# How to find the number of products against a manufacturer in multi dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm creating a web application where I need to show total count of products against a single manufacturer but I have to get that data from a multi dimensional array where multiple arrays contains same manufacturer id but represent different products

```
array:1 [▼
  "Concrete" => array:199 [▼
    0 => array:26 [▼
      "fav_yes" => ""
      "id" => 1440
      "name" => "Citrox 600"
      "mfg_id" => 88
    ]
    1 => array:26 [▼
      "fav_yes" => ""
      "id" => 191
      "name" => "Crackbond CSR"
      "mfg_id" => 88

    ]
    2 => array:26 [▼
      "fav_yes" => ""
      "id" => 1305
      "name" => "980 Grout & Tile Cleaner"
      "mfg_id" => 260
      "mfg_name" => "Diedrich Technologies, Inc."

    ]
"Mension" => array:199 [▼
0 => array:26 [▼
      "fav_yes" => ""
      "id" => 1361
      "name" => "C-Tar Melt"
      "mfg_id" => 260
    ]
    1 => array:26 [▼
      "fav_yes" => ""
      "id" => 1306
      "name" => "960 HD Concrete Cleaner"
      "mfg_id" => 260
]
```

I need to show total number of `name` as against `mfg_id` after iterating through whole the array.
Expected output is
mfg_id = 2 because the occurrence of name against mfg_id 88 is 2 times
and for mfg_id 260 the result is 3 because the number of occurrences of a name against this id is 3.

Comment: An what exactly is your problem here? What have you tried so far? Give us some code you're struggling with. Maybe read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines and edit your Question accordingly.

Comment: Meaning..... What is your expected output?

Comment: expected output updated @DrakulaPredatorم

Comment: you mean `[88 => 2, 260 => 3]` ?

Comment: exactly @DrakulaPredatorم

Comment: @AbdullahFaraz Once check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to visit each leaf,

> **Note**: array_walk_recursive is core php function which has its own scope. So, &$r will hold data saved into it in iteration else it will
>   reset it in every single iteration.
>   In other words,
>   **"By reference" means it's referring to the same allocated memory block for the variable being referred to.**

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($v, $k) use (&$r) {
    if ($k == 'mfg_id') { // checking if key is mfg id
        $r[$v] = (!empty($r[$v]) ? $r[$v] : 0) + 1; // increment as per value of mfg id
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oOI88)

If you need foreach version of it using [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php),

```
function assc_array_count_values( $array, $key ) {
     $new_array = [];
     foreach( $array as $row ) {
         foreach($row as $temp){
            $new_array[] = $temp[$key];    
         }
     }
     return array_count_values( $new_array );
}
// count by key name 
$temp = assc_array_count_values($arr, 'mfg_id');
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TcU26s).

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [88] => 2
    [260] => 3
)
```

Comment: what is `&$r` in 1st solution

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` returns 1 only not worked but  `array_count_values` works absolute fine

Comment: it doesn't return any value, I am saving result data in `$r` variable. if you `print_r($r);` in first solution it will work too. Please click on [demo](https://3v4l.org/oOI88) link below example given.